# Do you threaten spaces when Blinded?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, conditions, blind

We has a session where we were facing a werewolf. As a werewolf they have the [scent ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Scent). Our magic user then managed to [blind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded) the werewolf which lead us into the realm of rules bickering and confusion.

So we quickly figured out that it could use a move action to locate the direction of a creature, and if within 5 feet is able to pinpoint it regardless of vision. So it knew creatures adjacent to it and could find more.

The issue started with provoking attacks of AOO and flanking. According to the blind condition, nothing is mentioned about the creature losing the ability to threaten squares around it, thus it is able to grant flanking, benefit from flanking, and take AoO's.

Could someone please confirm that this is true or please show me the rules that prevents this?

Comment: Please give your questions more descriptive titles. As a tip, if you find yourself writing “[thing] and [thing]” as a title, it needs rewriting. Sometimes it helps to write the question first and the title last, so that it can accurately describe the crux of the question.

Comment: The titles can be more difficult than the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with [blindness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded).

> All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) against the blinded character.

The [scent ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Scent) allows a character to pinpoint a target's location, allowing it to make attacks against the appropriate square, but this does not remove the concealment.

> The creature detects another creature's presence but not its specific location. Noting the direction of the scent is a move action. If the creature moves within 5 feet (1 square) of the scent's source, the creature can pinpoint the area that the source occupies, even if it cannot be seen.

Finally, [concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment) means you cannot make attacks of opportunity. (Or, I think, grant/benefit from flanking, but I'm not sure about that one).

> You can't execute an attack of opportunity against an opponent with total concealment, even if you know what square or squares the opponent occupies.

Comment: I wasnt able to argue the point so that it prevented the werewolf from getting its AOO

Comment: @Fering I don't think stack exchange can answer something as subjective as how to win an argument or how to conduct a game, but it can equip you with the information to help come to the right conclusion. McCurran has given rules source on what blindness means and what total concealment means. I'd suggest not openly challenging GM's handling, bring it up in private and option that the wolf could somehow see for a brief moment and going forwards blind denies AOO.

Comment: Wasnt trying to win, was trying to have the right answer even if not mine